# Keep two directories synced in ubuntu in real time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

My intention is to keep two directories (say `dir1` & `dir2`) synced. So that whenever there is a change in the content of the `dir1` (can be addition or deletion of new file or directory or modifying the content of a file in the directory) then the change should be propagated to `dir2` and vice versa.

The naive way I can think of doing this is to run `rsync` periodically via `cron` in both the machines. But there are fallacies in this approach:-

1. It might happen that the previous `rsysnc` is not complete and the `cron` executed `rsync` once more while the previous `rysnc` is still going on.
2. A new file is added in `dir1` and before `rsync` ran on `dir2` `rsync` on `dir1` ran then newly added file might be deleted from `dir1` since it is not present in `dir2`
3. Also this is not real time.

Can some suggest some better way of doing this?

Comment: Is using symlinks not an option here?

Comment: The directory can be on different hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strongly depends on the purpose. 'Realtime' is probably not the term you are looking for.

Take a look at https://www.gluster.org/ (Replicated Mode) for a synchronous replication via network.

Comment: My purpose is - I have an application server which will read/write files to disk. I have multiple instances of the application server so they need a common storage to read and write data. My intention is to avoid the single point of failure in the network file storage. Because of the nature of the application server that I have I can only read / write from file storage. So I can not use any DBs for this task. I am looking for some opensource solution which is easier to set-up and get started.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like you are searching for a distributed filesystem. Another option would be http://ceph.com/. But if you want to get started easy - https://www.gluster.org/ is the right choice for you (IMO).